# test backbonejs with mocha on nodejs

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, requirejs, mocha.js

I have a nodejs application which has the client-side code build with backbonejs and requirejs.
I want to test the client-side code on my nodejs server using mocha.

My mocha test file:
test/view.coffee

```
requirejs = require 'requirejs'
global.define = requirejs

requirejs.config
  nodeRequire: require
  baseUrl: '../public/javascripts/libs/'
  paths:
    jquery: "jquery"
    Underscore: "underscore"
    Backbone: "backbone"
  shim:
    'jquery':
      exports: '$'
    'Underscore':
      exports: '_'
    'Backbone':
      deps: ['jquery', 'Underscore']
      exports: 'Backbone'

requirejs ['../public/javascripts/views/test_view'], (TestView) ->
  describe 'TestView', ->
    view = new TestView()
```

The Backbonejs file to be tested:
public/javascripts/views/test_view.coffee

```
define [
  'Backbone'
], (Backbone) ->
  class TestView extends Backbone.View
    initialize: ->
      ...
  TestView
```

In public/javascripts/libs I have the minified (not AMD) versions of jquery, backbone, and underscore.

When I run my test I get the following error message:

```
Error: Calling node's require("../public/javascripts/views/test_view")
failed with error: Error: Calling node's require("Underscore")
failed with error: Error: Cannot find module 'Underscore'
  at /node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2262:27
```

Somehow the paths attribute of requirejs.config in test/view.coffee is not read.
If I remove Backbone: "backbone" from paths, I dont't get an error message that the module 'Backbone' is missing.
I didn't install Backbone and Underscore on the nodejs server.

**Edit:**
Fixed the problem with the path by changing requirejs.config baseUrl to 'public/javascripts/views/test_view'. Requirejs is not using the path of the file (test/view.coffee) for the baseUrl block. For the requirejs ['...'], (TestView) part I have to use the path of the test/view.coffee file.

When I run my test with mocha I get the following error:

```
throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Calling node's require("../public/javascripts/views/test_view")
  failed with error: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'load'
```

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that I've added 'jade!templates/test_template' to my test_view.
I removed it, and now mocha is running the test. But I get the error:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
  at Object.CALL_NON_FUNCTION_AS_CONSTRUCTOR (native)
```

the line:

```
view = new TestView()
```

is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that on the server, RequireJS falls back to node's require(). A possible solution would be to install Backbone with NPM, and symlink node_modules/backbone/backbone.js to public/lib/backbone.js. You could then require backbone using either node's or RequireJS' require().

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed the error by updating requirejs.config baseUrl: to 'public/javascripts/libs/'. I will update my question.